# SaltStack: How do I configure the minion to use a different publisher port?

Tags: port-forwarding, saltstack

Now I am having a `salt-master` behind an NAT, the master's 4505 and 4506 ports have been mapped to the 44505 and 44506 ports on the router.

There's a `master_port` option but I think that only changes the port 4506 to 44506. How do I configure the minion to use 44505 instead of 4505 when connecting to this master?

Answer (score 1):

**Important** update 10/14/2015:

It was my fault - my network was not good so some working methods may have been thought not working... I will keep my old answer, but it didn't seem correct - it failed after I rebooted both my minion and master.

What seems to work now is:

I put `publish_port: 44505` in the file `/etc/salt/master` on the master, so salt opens port 44505 on the master now. Then I changed the port mapping configuration on the router, to map the router's port 44505 to master's port 44505 (instead of 4505).

I don't know what the mechanism is, but it seems that the master can tell the minion which publish port to use, therefore the **public port number on the router** should be consistent with the **local port number on the master**.

Now my `/etc/salt/minion` configuration is just:

```
master: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
master_port: 44506
```

---

The original answer which is **WRONG**:

I think I made it work by simply using the same `publish_port` option in the minion configuration file. I don't think it is mentioned on the documentation. It is **NOT** in the default `/etc/salt/minion` configuration file either.

Now my `/etc/salt/minion` configuration is like:

```
master: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
publish_port: 44505
master_port: 44506
```

Simply adding `publish_port: 44505` to the `/etc/salt/master` configuration file on master does not make its minions connect to that publish port automatically. You will need to explicitly specify it in your minion configuration.